# Free / Open source program to solve limits, integrals and series. And then show the solution process step by step.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, programming

The title pretty much says it all. I'm looking for a free / open source program to solve limits, integrals and infinite series (pretty much basic calculus problems) and show a step by step solution that is humanly feasible. Mainly for educational purposes (I teach calculus).

A quick online search unearths a plethora of online solvers, but I was looking specifically for one based on open source technology.

https://gamma.sympy.org/ is exactly what I mean, but it only provides clean step by step solutions for integrals. I also need limits and series.

I would also be contempt with more "programming-language-oriented" solutions to my questions, such as an API.

Thanks in advance for any tip.